# Accessing a shared directory inside GKE from an external world

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nfs, file-sharing

I am newbie to Google Cloud and GKE and i am trying to setup NFS Persistent Volumes with Kubernetes on GKE with the help of following link :
https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266

I had followed the instructions and i was able to achieve the desired results as mentioned in the blog but i need to access the shared folder (/uploads) from an external world so can someone help me to achieve it or any pointers or any suggestions to achieve the same

Comment: Please look in to this docs (https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-nfs-persistent-volume-kubernetes/):

nfs:
    path: /opt/k8s-pods/data
    server: 192.168.1.40

Comment: @Mahboob The Server here (192.168.1.40) is a external VM not the GKE cluster but a separate VM where we are setting up NFS manually but there is a readymade image itself from Google Cloud Registry but my problem is more towards how to expose the mount path to the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the [doc](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266) and implemented the steps on my test GKE cluster like you. Just I have one observation about the current API version for deployment. We need to use apiVersion: apps/v1 instead of apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1. Then I test with a busybox pod to mount the volume and the test was successful.

[image: BusyBox POD]

Then I exposed the service “nfs-server” as service type “Load Balancer” like below

[image: Expose nfs-server]

and found the external load balancer endpoints like (LB_Public_Ip):111 in Services & Ingress tab. I allowed ports 111, 2049, 20048 in firewall. After that I took a redhat based VM in the GCP project and installed “sudo dnf install nfs-utils -y”.  Then you may use the below command to see the nfs exports list. Then you can mount it as expected.

-sudo showmount -e LB_Public_IP

Comment: I tried the same but within my GCP project i have brought up a REDHAT instance when i entered showmount -e <public_ip> and it throwed a error clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused). Can i use my local VM's to connect to the GKE pod and run the command showmount -e from my local VM ? Any suggestions on this will really help

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on the below sample configuration and you may follow the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares#create_a_persistent_volume)

[image: Sample Config]

Comment: The problem is File Store instances are having 1 TB as minimum and cost goes to 200 dollars for a month so i was looking for alternative as i hardly store 10 GB of data in the disk.